# Can't find Desktop files

Tags: wine, icons, .desktop, dock

So I tried installing League of Legends using Wine and lutris but then decided I did not want that game on my Computer anymore.
I uninstalled it from the computer but the icons for it is still in the dock.
The icon doesn't work anymore it is just there.
I would like to remove it. I have been trying to find the .desktop file for this icons but had no luck.
I looked here ~/.local/share/applications and in the usr file.
I also tried searching for all .desktop files.
I cant find any desktop file that has league in the name to delete it from the dock. I even tried installing this app called AppEditor which allows you to edit your dock.
It recognised the league icon was there. I deleted it using this app but it did not disappear. This app worked for other icons though. Just those icons it would not remove.

Comment: Do you have in mind that the file doesn't need to have "league" in its file name? Probably, you could try searching for files "*.desktop" with the broken route in its content with a command like `grep`.